SSAS Dimension Processing: Why use ProcessUpdate when ProcessFull is faster?
I have a question about which processing option should be used for SSAS dimensions.
I heard that ProcessFull option is faster than ProcessUpdate, and I found that it is the case. I have a big dimension of a cube, which takes about 90 mins to process using ProcessUpdate, took only 40 minutes by using ProcessFull. Time is saved by half!
Also, given at some point of time of dimension processing, ProcessFull would be necessary, then why should ProcessUpdate be used at all? Please advise.
